# Performance warning when adding columns to pandas frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

I come across the following warning after inserting multiple columns to a pandas data frame:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

I have a number of different results and pass them to the data frame as follows, e.g.:

`df_result ["Albedo_Surface_Irradiance_0 [W/m²]"] = AlbedoSurf_irradiance[0]`

`df_result ["Albedo_Surface_Irradiance_1 [W/m²]"] = AlbedoSurf_irradiance[1]`

`...`

The warning contains an advice to use `pd.concat(axis=1)` and joining all columns at once, I couldn't figure out how to do so.

I tried following the advice that appeared in the terminal, but it didn't work. I also tried another provided solution in a similar question using

`df_result [["Albedo_Surface_Irradiance_0 [W/m²]","Albedo_Surface_Irradiance_1 [W/m²]", ... ]] = (AlbedoSurf_irradiance[0], AlbedoSurf_irradiance[1])`

unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: What is the specific error you're seeing when you try `pd.concat`? The correct syntax for this problem may look something like: `pd.concat([df_result, AlbedoSurf_irradiance], axis=1)` or `pd.concat([df_result, AlbedoSurf_irradiance.transpose()], axis=1)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find any good examples for pd.concat to just add columns to an existing data frame like I want to do it assigning every single column to a certain array. The examples always create a new dataframe adding columns to an older dataframe.

Comment: There is no technical difference between adding columns to a "new" dataframe and adding columns to an "existing" dataframe. In both cases - you are adding columns. Your problem is still not clear.